# How to code a rectangles that start from right in circular motion in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

The problem is that I want to draw small square/rect  in a circle from left to right. Somewhat like this:

[image]

In pygame, the rectangles number should be 120.

But whenever use this function:

```py
x = int(math.cos(angle) * 50) + origin X
y = int(math.sin(angle) * 50) + origin Y
```

It starts from two different points, and if I adjust the angle it starts at five different points.

[image]

I want it to start from right in full circle.

```py
import pygame, sys, math
run = True
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
angle = 0
size = widht, height = 800, 600
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    msElapsed = clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    screen.fill(white)
    i = 1
    while i < 28:
        x = int(math.cos(angle) * 100) + 300
        y = int(math.sin(angle) * 100) + 200
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (x, y, 10, 10))

        i += 1
        angle += 5
        print(x)
        print(y)
        pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quite()
```

and output are

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't verify that. In general that should work fine. You've to show more code. What are the values for `angle`?

Comment: I HAVE EDIT THE QUESTION--                                                                                          please help --- thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

The unit of the angle for [Trigonometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry) functions (e.g. `math.cos`, `math.sin`) in the [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) module is [Radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) rather than degree. `math.pi*2` Radian is 360 Degrees.

If you want to distribute 28 rectangles uniformly around a circle, then the angle from 1 rectangle to the next is `math.pi*2 / 28`. e.g.:

```py
run = True
while run:
    msElapsed = clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    screen.fill(white)
    
    for i in range(28):
        angle = i / 28 * math.pi * 2 # 2*pi radian == 360°
        x = int(math.cos(angle) * 100) + 400
        y = int(math.sin(angle) * 100) + 300
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (x-5, y-5, 10, 10))
    
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image]